# Ошибка при билде

Tags: unity3d

Ошибки в консоли:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()
```

```
Exception occurred inside BeeDriver: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "D:\unity\Game\Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aPDevDbg.dag\UnityEngine.UI.dll.mvfrm"
File name: 'D:\unity\Game\Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aPDevDbg.dag\UnityEngine.UI.dll.mvfrm'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00055] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) [0x00000] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(string,System.Text.Encoding)
  at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllLines (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) [0x00006] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (System.String path) [0x0002c] in <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0 
  at NiceIO.NPath+SystemIOFileSystem.File_ReadAllLines (NiceIO.NPath path) [0x00007] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at NiceIO.NPath+WindowsFileSystem.File_ReadAllLines (NiceIO.NPath path) [0x00017] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at NiceIO.NPath.ReadAllLines () [0x00005] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.PotentiallyUpdatableErrorMessages.IsAnyPotentiallyUpdatable (UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerMessage[] messages, Bee.BeeDriver.NodeResult nodeResult, Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver beeDriver) [0x000ba] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityScriptUpdater.ContainsUpdatableCompilerMessage (Bee.BeeDriver.NodeResult nodeResult, Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver beeDriver) [0x0008e] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.UnityScriptUpdater.StartIfYouCanFixProblemsInTheseMessages (Bee.BeeDriver.NodeResult nodeResult, Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver beeDriver) [0x00001] in <99feab6f3db6407493924fe4a179a95b>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.RunSourceFileUpdatingPhase.StartIfNeedToRunFor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nodeResults) [0x00047] in <8090e176693344d890ff5ce732f8fade>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.RunBackendPhase.Tick () [0x001f2] in <8090e176693344d890ff5ce732f8fade>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.PhaseBase.Tick (System.Boolean blocked) [0x00009] in <8090e176693344d890ff5ce732f8fade>:0 
  at Bee.BeeDriver.BeeDriver.Tick (System.Boolean block) [0x00000] in <8090e176693344d890ff5ce732f8fade>:0
```

Comment: Это читали? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588940/8324991 или это https://answers.unity.com/questions/459810/error-building-player-because-scripts-had-compiler-1.html

Comment: В своих скриптах я не использовал unityEditor. До этого игра билдилась

Answer (score 0):

1. Перевод ошибки:

> Внутри BeeDriver произошло исключение:
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: не удалось найти файл
> "D:\unity\Game\Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aPDevDbg.dag\UnityEngine.UI.dll.mvfrm"

**Как это исправить?**

Закрыть Unity, удалить папку artifacts и снова запустить Unity, это должно решить проблему, после запуска в консоли могут быть ошибки - это нормально, просто нажмите на Clear. И снова попробуете собрать проект.

Если снова появиться ошибки при сборке, то у вас скорее всего проблемы с Антивирусом или с правами администратора.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, ничего не поменялось